# X divide Y and minimum is 1

Tags: javascript, c#, math

When I divide x = 20 over y = 7, 20 / 7 = 2.857 I will take the result as is.

However if the result is lesser than 1, I would take 1, so

15 / 20 = 1

Right now I can do something like this:

```
If x > y then
   result = x / y
else
   result = 1
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: are you using c++?

Comment: i think ur in good way to do it

Comment: C# or Javascript @active92

Comment: @StevenYong for c#, you can either use what you have now or check out `math.ceiling`

Comment: `max(x / y, 1)`  ?

Comment: @ryan I think the max function is what I am looking for. Will you please post your comment as answer? mukul and eak, your answers are useful too!

Comment: @StevenYong, if this is the only incidence in the code you are using any of the Math function, then I feel loading Math library in the memory is costly.

Comment: @mukul, you have got a point there! And point taken.

Comment: Your sample code works for positive x, y only. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below

```
var x = 20.0;
var y = 7.0;

var result = (x > y) ? x / y : 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 result = x/y;

 switch(result)
 {
    case result<1 :
      result = 1
      break;
  }
```